# Save battery life while updating location in obj c?

Tags: objective-c, location, battery

How to **save** our iphone Battery life while Updating our current location ? Since i am updating current location but battery **Drain** very fast. Can someone Help me ?

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the fact that the locationManager will continue updating location until and unless it is not stopped soo you should stop updating location when you're done with it.

Just call when you finished Updating location :-

```
[self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]
```

Comment: thank for  your valuable reply. Actually , i am updating my location for particular period of time. When i end with my period i call this method.[self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]. But how to save our battery while the Updating loaction is in process ?

Comment: you can start it when you need it and you can also put this in a button or something like that when you're finished

Comment: i did that. it will stop updating my location and battery drain will be slow. But  i want such solution that save my  battery life when location managing is in process.

Comment: also have a look at this :- http://www.apple.com/in/batteries/maximizing-performance/